# Generate a list with repeated elements

Tags: erlang

I have:

```
ListOne = ['foo', 'bar', ..]
```

I now want to create a new List by zipping ListOne with ListTwo. ListTwo looks like this:

```
ListTwo = [{count, 1},{count, 1},{count,1}, ..]
```

What's a nice way to dynamically generate ListTwo? Every list item will be the same.

I want to feed the result of the zip to `dict:from_list`. So maybe a zip is not the best approach.

Comment: what is {count:1}? do you mean {count, 1}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your question could be more specific, my guess is that you want to use a dictionary to store key, value pairs where the value is a counter. What you are trying to achieve by asking this, is how to initialize the dict with the counter set to 1.

The folloing code will create a new dict, where the key is the key from ListOne and the value is 1:

```
ListOne = [foo, bar, baz, quux].
D1 = dict:from_list([{Elem, 1} || Elem <- ListOne]).
```

Now, to increment these counters, you can use `dict:update_counter/3`:

```
D2 = dict:update_counter(foo, 1, D1).
```

To decrement, you would simply give a negative number as the increment.

It is also worth noting that `dict:update_counter/3`, will create the key in the dict if it is not already present, with the given increment as the initial value.

Comment: I see that this answer solves your problem by eliminating the need for ListTwo, but for anyone who finds this question via google or similar and really needs to dynamically build a list of repeating elements, consider lists:duplicate/2 http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#duplicate-2

Answer (score 3):

I'm not if this is what you are exactly looking for, but if ListTwo is something like this :  [{count,1}, {count,1},.....] you may generate it with:

`ListTwo = [{count, 1} || _X <- lists:seq(1,5)].`

I think that each argument of ListTwo is a tuple, thus you should separate the two value with ","...otherwise if your example is correct you may do something as:

`ListTwo = [{'count:1'} || _X <- lists:seq(1,5)].`

obviously you should pick the right range for the size of your list (in my example from 1 to 5)